# Please install STM32CubeIDE toolchain to open the project

Tags: stm32cubemx, stm32cubeide

I want to create a project with STM32CubeMX, but when I say Generate Code,
"Please install STM32CubeIDE toolchain to open the project. Or associate the file type of the project with your Toolchain in System Default Program settings."
I get an error. What do I need to do?

Comment: Have you installed the stm32 cube ide?

Comment: I didn't download it when I got this error, then I downloaded it. I choose stm32CubeIDE in the Toolchain/IDE section and when I say Generate Code, the code opens in Stm32IDE. But I need to choose MDK-ARM in this part. If I choose this, my codes do not open in KeiluVision.